# SQL: regex for removing certain part of a string

Tags: sql, regex

How can I remove `{color:#de350b}` and `{color}` from:

```
{color:#de350b}FA_RDA_CORE-DEC-20220325122114-210-981{color}
```

to get:

```
FA_RDA_CORE-DEC-20220325122114-210-981
```

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Please also add what you aready tried, which regex you used. With sites like https://regex101.com/ you can even share them with examples

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica, note that diffent dbms products have different regexp implementations.

Comment: I've tried this: REGEXP_SUBSTR(substr(dbms_lob.substr(evidence, 2000),100). It didn't work.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The answer will most probably be product specific.

Comment: @jarlh, i'm using sql developer

Comment: Then add the <oracle> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Good day.
Can you try this? Please don't forget substitution with "$5".

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aDJzUf/1)ttps://regex101.com/r/aDJzUf/1